# What is the equivalent node.js Buffer in java?

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js

I could not adapt some algorithm in js to java.

I have tried

```java
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.alocate(10);

buffer.put((byte)10000,0);
```

it could not fix my problem. Also I tried byte array.

In javascript there is a code ;

```
...
var buf = new Buffer.alloc(10);
buf.writeUInt16LE(10000,0);
buf.write("test",5);
...
```

What is the equivalent buffer, buffer.write(), buffer.writeUInt16LE?

If there is not how can i figure out about this problem?

I would be very happy if someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no true equivalent unless you want to write your own class. `byte[]` arrays provide the basic functionality and is what  byte-oriented I/O tends to use. `ByteBuffer` is another class that you can think of as a wrapper for `byte[]` that provides some additional convenient functionality including endian-specific transformations. `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` also covers some of the same ground but use big-endian exclusively for `short`, `char`, `int`, and `long` I/O.

Comment: Thanks for advice, i figure out that situtation.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem;

Firstly, in java I found that if we want to use little endian algorithm in bytebuffer there is a function that helps us for making encyription.

```java
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

after that I used putShort function for adding Unsigned 16 bit encyrpted data to the buffer, for Unsigned byte(UInt8) type in javascript I used put function and for Unsigned Integer(UInt32) type in javascript I used putInteger function.

Thanks.